# I can't execute rqt_graph in ROS fuerte

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody!

I have used rqt-graph several times in ROS Fuerte, but now I can't use it. When I try to execute the command rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph, the answer is:
[rospack] Error: stack/package rqt_graph not found

Obviously, I've tried to reinstall with:
$ sudo apt-get install ros-<distro>-rqt
$ sudo apt-get install ros--rqt-common-plugins

but the results is always the same:
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
E: No se ha podido localizar el paquete ros-fuerte-rqt-common-plugins

¿Can anybody help me?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74269/i-can%27t-execute-rqt_graph-in-ros-fuerte./) by [Meee](https://answers.ros.org/users/6097/meee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please use the following.

I really hope you did this in first case itself
 is your distribution.

First verify which version of ros do you have.

$ rosversion ros

if you get the following for example:
1.8.11
it means it is ***ROS fuerte***

replace ,distro> with **fuerte**

- $ sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-rqt

or if you have groovy then it is

- $ sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-rqt

Please try! all the best

If there be any of the dependent rospacks that miss for the rqt please type the following and check if you got all of them as listed below:

natraj@natraj-MacBookPro:~$ rospack depends rqt_graph
rosbuild
python_qt_binding
qt_gui
rqt_gui
qt_dotgraph
rosgraph
roslib
rosnode
rostopic
rosservice

I hope it helps you.

---

Originally posted by [Ashutosh_Oxford](https://answers.ros.org/users/8276/ashutosh_oxford/) with karma: 16 on 2013-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0